# Webdriver IO junit xml for xray - Could someone help me to add customproperty for test case - test key

Tags: jira-xray, wdio

I want to add a custom property for the test case - the test key. This junit xml needs to be imported to xray. So that the test case execution results can be updated based on test key or test ID
Could someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to use the [built-in junit reporter](https://webdriver.io/docs/junit-reporter) provided by webdriverio for adding custom `testcase` properties (to be able to include the test_key information).

An option would be to implement your own custom reporter for that purpose, eventually as a fork of the current implementation.